# How to correctly start a C and C++ IAR embedded project?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, iar

I am currently working on an embedded project for the stm32f3. In this project I want to use both `.cpp` and `.c` files:
The C files are for the UART/I2C... initialisation files while the C++ ones are for a more object oriented solution. Therefore I really need to keep both of them.
My question is how to make it work properly? I have seen a few answer on the web but it all seem very confusing to me.

I already had a project with `uart.c/h` files inside a C++ project (the board was working just fine), but as I added a `i2c.c/h` files to the project, a lot of linkage errors appeared.

Example = `Error[Li005]: no definition for "I2C_StructInit" [referenced from C:\Users\IAR Embedded Workbench\STM32F3-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0\Project\I2C Interface CPU\Debug\Obj\i2c.o]`

Should the `main` be a C or C++ file?

Should I use `Language\Auto` in the project setting, or specify for each file to compile in C or C++ ?

When do I need to use `extern "C"`?

I am using IAR Embedded Workbench IDE.
Any other advices are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this platform, but the problems sound pretty general.

> Should the `main` be a C or C++ file?

C++ would be the safer choice because `main` relates to program initialization, and C++ implements dynamic initialization unlike C.

> When do I need to use `extern "C"`?

This is important, and a likely source of your problem. You need `extern "C"` to decorate every declaration used in C++ whose definition is provided in C.

If your C headers lack `extern "C"`, you can in a pinch add it for them:

```
extern "C" {
#include "i2c.h"
}
```

Putting a `#include` directive inside anything is generally a very bad idea, but this is relatively harmless because `extern "C" {}` doesn't introduce a new, nested declarative scope, aside from modifying the linkage of declarations contained within.

As Mine suggests, you could also modify the header files to contain `extern "C"` when compiling in C++ mode. My advice is based on the idea that modifying a library is the greater evil. In my experience, embedded drivers may be dynamically generated for the platform, or in any case you might move later to a slightly different platform. You should use the idiom in that answer for your own headers, but personally I'd avoid editing `i2c.h` at all costs.

Answer (score 3):

In your .h files, you should probably write like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

xxxxx // Your header file content

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then you can include such .h files in both .c and .cpp code without problem.

Note the trick is, all these functions are without c++ decorations, so both c and c++ see the same function names.

Comment: If I understand correctly all my `.h` files should be included in this frame right? It doesn't matter if I declare a C++ functions inside `extern "C" {}` ?

Comment: @AntoineAndrieu Only C declarations should go inside `extern C` block.

Comment: @AntoineAndrieu Yes, because `#ifdef __cplusplus` makes sure only c++ sees the `extern "C"`, so you can write all .h files this way.

Answer (score 2):

About the IAR specific stuff:

`Language\Auto` makes compiler determine language from file extension `.c/.cpp`. Be aware though that IAR (5.4 at least) only supports subset of C++, and not all features are available.

For everything else you asked: see Potatoswatters answer about the `extern` and `main`.

Comment: Should I therefore use `language\C++` ?

Comment: @AntoineAndrieu No, if you use both languages, then leave it on `Auto` and use correct file extensions to select language for the file.